# Uncountable posets with countable width and height

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

In a seminar I listened in on, it was referenced that under (a weaker form of) AC, Sierpinski showed that there's a poset $(P, <)$ with $|P| > \aleph_0$ such that the width and height of $P$ is countable. However, I wasn't able to find any reference to it online. Can anyone help find his paper which showed this result, or if they know his result can share what he wrote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ be a set of distinct real numbers, and define a strict partial order $\prec$ on $\omega_1$ by setting $\alpha\prec\beta$ iff $\alpha<\beta$ **and** $x_\alpha<x_\beta$. There is no strictly increasing $\omega_1$-sequence in $\Bbb R$ — this follows readily from the separability of $\Bbb R$ — so there is no uncountable chain in $\langle\omega_1,\prec\rangle$. Similarly, the fact that there is no strictly decreasing $\omega_1$-sequence in $\Bbb R$ ensures that $\langle\omega_1,\prec\rangle$ has no uncountable antichain.

I have seen this example attributed to W. Sierpiński, *Sur un problème de la théorie des relations*, Annali della Scuola
Normale Superiore di Pisa (Classe di Scienze) 2 (1933), 285–287.

Comment: As always, amazing answers. Thank you!

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain: You’re welcome!